# Exportar função utilizando package de terceiro

Tags: javascript, node.js

Possuo um trecho de código que utilizo para consumir uma `API` e uso este mesmo trecho em diversos arquivos. Sendo assim criei um módulo para exportar tal configuração:

```
'use strict'

// Module to access woocommerce API endpoints
var woocommerceAPI = require('woocommerce-api')

// Load the environment configuration
require('dotenv').config()

module.exports = () => {
  return new woocommerceAPI({
    url: process.env.URL,
    consumerKey: process.env.CONSUMERKEY,
    consumerSecret: process.env.CONSUMERSECRET,
    version: process.env.VERSION
  })
```

}

Quando retorno a instancia do package `woocommerceAPI` o mesmo deveria conter a função `get`, ficando da seguinte maneira.

```
const wc = require('./wc-config')

wc.get('products', (err, data, res) => {
  console.log(res)
})
```

Porém só recebo a mensagem de que `wc.get` não é uma função.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repara que o teu ficheiro/modulo está a exportar uma função e não uma instância de `woocommerceAPI`.

Quando tens `module.exports = () => {...}` isso exporta `() => {...}`, o que queres ter é `module.exports = new woocommerceAPI(...);` ao estilo Singleton.

Assim o código deveria ser:

```
'use strict'

// Module to access woocommerce API endpoints
const woocommerceAPI = require('woocommerce-api')

// Load the environment configuration
require('dotenv').config()

const WooAPI = new woocommerceAPI({
    url: process.env.URL,
    consumerKey: process.env.CONSUMERKEY,
    consumerSecret: process.env.CONSUMERSECRET,
    version: process.env.VERSION
})
module.exports = WooAPI
```